# Adding an image doesn't count as an edit?

Tags: discussion, bug, editing, voting

Adding an image to a post doesn't seem to count as an edit for voting purposes. Is that correct?

I downvoted [Turn off text wrapping in Indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/22134/turn-off-text-wrapping-in-indesign) because it was missing its image and added a comment. The OP added the image, possibly while I was posting. I saw this some time later and wanted to undo my downvote, but the site tells me my 'vote is locked in unless the question is edited'. What up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact that he added an image isn't relevant, it's "ninja-editing" that doesn't reset things for voting. Any edits made within 5 minutes of posting will not show up in the revision history. Only once there is something in the revision history can you change your vote.

More info here: [**Cannot retract downvote if post has been edited within first 5 minutes of posting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/62219/216955)

Comment: Thanks, JohnB! Good to know it's a known bug.